# How does the device knows an app is installed before?

Tags: protected-apps

Some apps gives premium support for some limited time. If I uninstalled and installed it next time I couldn't get the same features. How does the application keeps a record of the device? And is it possible to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

Applications might use techniques, such as hidden files, benign modifications to other files ... some have even been known to write to hidden parts of your hard disk.

So basically when you install the program it probably writes a hidden file or entry in your phone to "mark" that phone and let it know that you've already done the trial period.  It also probably keeps track of your e-mail address that is linked to your google play account or itunes store account, maybe even keeps track of your phone's id(depending on how deep these programs go.)

Comment: It may also be possible that the app reads the device id and checks if it has a record of it in a database. Just so you know, how apps are able to identify your device even after a hard reset.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was gearing towards on the last part of my final sentence, when I said it keeps track of your phone's id number.